# Can we burn the game-rec tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Recently, this question was asked:

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/254329/where-can-i-find-a-top-100-of-all-videogames

It has since been put on hold.

Between the question being opened and then put on hold, an edit was made to link it to the [game-rec](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-rec) tag.

This tag is only linked to this one question, but was a previously used tag prior to game recommendations being off-topic.

Is it possible to burn the tag?

Comment: The question will be deleted at the latest in 9 days, at the earliest whenever (20k and mod can vote to delete now). It'll be taken care of

Comment: I'm not even sure why anyone would create/approve creation of such a tag. It's clearly off-topic in nature.

Comment: It is an historic tag, that was recently re-used.  During the early years it was on-topic.

Comment: Tags don't exist without questions, once the question is deleted the tag will be removed as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the only question with this tag has been deleted, this is now resolved.